# Why does ng-include break my collapse menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I recently bought a template to start pulling an application I am building into it. The navigation will have a lot of dynamic menus based on the user's roles so I would like to keep it in a separate file and pull it in versus putting it on every page and updating each one. When I do use ng-include, it seems like Jquery breaks or bootstrap.min.js doesn't recognize the menus.

```
<div ng-include="'/partials/structure/navigation.html'"></div>
```

When I do the above it pulls in the navigation, just the mobile menu of it's not clickable. No errors in the console either. On a full view, the menus are there and all the dropdowns work. When I don't use ng-include both full menu and mobile menu function as you would expect. So it seems like something with jQuery, but I am stumped where to look for this and Google didn't yield much to go off of.

```
                    <div class="menu-extras topbar-custom">

                     <ul class="list-inline float-right mb-0">

                        <li class="menu-item list-inline-item">
                            <!-- Mobile menu toggle-->
                            <a class="navbar-toggle nav-link">
                                <div class="lines">
                                    <span></span>
                                    <span></span>
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <!-- End mobile menu toggle-->
                        </li> 
                        <!-- Removed code to shorten things for you guys -->
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                <!-- end menu-extras -->
```

Shortening this up as well.

```
            <div class="navbar-custom">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="navigation">
                    <!-- Navigation Menu-->
                    <ul class="navigation-menu">

                        <li class="has-submenu">
                            <a href="index.html"><i class="ti-home"></i>Dashboard</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="has-submenu">
                            <a href="#"><i class="ti-paint-bucket"></i>UI Kit</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="ui-buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ui-cards.html">Cards</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ui-portlets.html">Portlets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ui-checkbox-radio.html">Checkboxs-Radios</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ui-tabs.html">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ui-modals.html">Modals</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ui-progressbars.html">Progress Bars</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ui-notification.html">Notification</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ui-bootstrap.html">BS Elements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ui-typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                   </ul>
              </div>
```

Here is how I include everything before the  tag.

```
        <!-- jQuery  -->
    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script><!-- Popper for Bootstrap --><!-- Tether for Bootstrap -->
    <script src="../js/waves.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>

    <!-- App js -->
    <script src="../js/jquery.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.app.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="../js/controllers/main.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Javascript -->
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include `ng-include` it means after only the Angular application initialization directive will render the `HTML` content into the `DOM`. After that only the `bootstrap.min.js` can see the rendered menu HTML inside DOM. Therefore you need to add `bootstrap.min.js` after the `angular` code. Otherwise it won't see the HTML.

Therefore make sure you include `js` in following order

```
jquery.js
angular.js
angular application js code
bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: Reviewed the code and pasted in the original question at the bottom how I know have it. Same issue still is happening. I also thought it was an order in which way the DOM loads.

Comment: `ng-include` works through `AJAX` calls to the server. Make sure your HTML file receives from the server quickly in mobile devices.